# Is there a jQuery equivalent to CSS3 background-clip?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to create a scrolling image inside the text, I've created a working version using CSS3 background-clip and animations, but this isn't cross-browser compatible.

I have tried simply scrolling the image with jquery behind an image with the text sliced out but that presents problems with resizing the page, hover states, etc.

Here's a fiddle with the CSS3 version using keyframes and -webkit-backround-clip: http://jsfiddle.net/tbLV6/

```
  h1 { 
     background: url(image.jpeg) no-repeat;
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
     -webkit-animation: travelGalaxy 10s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: travelGalaxy 10s linear infinite;
     -o-animation: travelGalaxy 10s linear infinite;
  }

 @-moz-keyframes travelGalaxy {
    0% {background-position: right top;}
    100% {background-position: left top;}
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes travelGalaxy {
    0% {background-position: right top;}
    100% {background-position: left top;}
 }
```

Are there any jQuery / Javascript only methods that will accomplish this same result?

*Or perhaps an alternate method to accomplishing this task in a way that will work on IE?*

Comment: for animation/transition, if something works in CSS, its better to use CSS over javascript/jquery because CSS can take advantage of hardware acceleration

Comment: @roasted While it may be better, I'm going to assume he has to support IE, which is why he's asking for a cross-browser compatible solution.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock oh ya, i didn't see this part of the question.

Comment: Thanks roasted, I wish I could just use the CSS version, but @AndrewPeacock is right I need IE Support as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (Codepen) that uses a polyfill which replaces the specified element with a SVG in browser where -webkit-background-clip: text is not available:

http://bit.ly/1wjC6Rc